# SQL query add a number to int table data

Tags: sql, database

I want to add a certain number to all the table row data of a certain table column in int type.

To explain

example i have this kind of table on my database.

```
------------------------
|   Name   |   Money   |
------------------------
|John      |20         |
|Jake      |30         |
------------------------
```

Then i want go add both of their money with 500.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
update your_table
set `money` = `money` + 500
```

to add `500` to column `money` of all rows. Use

```
update your_table
set `money` = `money` + 500
where name in ('John', 'Jake')
```

to update only this two entries according to their `name`.

Comment: @Gelo103097.. Even I agree with above query and if you find it helped you then mark it as answer. Its best what you can give than Thanks.. :)

Comment: i know i should do that. Its not like you could press it immediately right? it has a cooldown